# why Gridbag layout is not showing the complete components on it

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, gridbaglayout, border-layout

I have 2D array of Jlabels and want to put them like a table using grid bag layout in a panel. the I put the panel into another panel with border layout
but i dont get the complete Jlabel.
thanks!

```
  setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(550, 550));

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                gbc.gridy = j;
                gbc.gridx = i;
                cells[i][j] = new Cell(emptyCell);// subclass of Jlabel
                cells[i][j].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
                add(cells[i][j],gbc);
            }
```

what i get
[image]

what the real cell is

[image]

Comment: Post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(550, 550));
```

Don't use the setPreferredSize() method on components:

1. each component should be responsible for determining its own size (ie. override the `getpreferredSize()` method to return the size.
2. for a panel the layout manager will determine the preferred size based on the rules of the layout manager and the components added to the panel.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not a complete answer, but you should set .fill to .BOTH and .weightx and .weighty to 1.0. As it is, the cells tend to collapse.

When I do Swing--not that often--I prefer GridBagLayout. However, you must become familiar with it to get it to do what you want.